# show that the interval is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show that the interval $[0,1[$ is uncountable.

The simple way is to construct a bijection between $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^*}$ and $[0,1[$.

Basically, using the [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument), if there is a bijection between $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^*}$ and $[0,1[$ then $[0,1[$ is uncountable! So, I need to prove that there is a bijection!

Using the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), if there exist injective functions $f: \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^*} \rightarrow [0,1[~$ and $g: [0,1[ \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^*}$ between the sets $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^*}$ and $[0,1[$, then there exists a bijective function h.

My problem is that I can't prove the second part! i.e to show that there injective functions satisfy the required relations.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you use Cantor's diagonal argument, you need no bijection. It is enough to show that the set of numbers starting with $0.$ and having only zeros and ones after the decimal point is already uncountable. The interval $[0,1]$ is a superset, so has to be uncountable then as well.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot! maybe I was not clear. In fact, I am reading alone a basic course in probability and analysis and I would like to learn how to prove this fact by constructing a bijection.

Comment: @Peter I was puzzled by that as well. Probly he's just referring to the diagonal argument to show that $\{0,,1\}^\Bbb N$ is uncountable...

Comment: The most simple way is to do as Cantor did: assume there is an enumeration and show it cannot work using completeness/compactness ideas. This was in fact his own original approach. He never used a diagonal argument for the reals or its subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an element in $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N^*}$, and interpret it as the (base ten) decimals in a number between $0$ and $1$. That gives you an injection $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N^*}\to [0,1[$. For the other direction, for each number in $[0,1[$, take its *binary* representation, and there you have an element of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N^*}$. This is an injection.

PS. Note that a few elements of $[0,1[$ have two binary representations, analoguous to the well-known $0.999\ldots = 1$ thing. You can decide whether you want to go with the one with infinitely many $0$'s, or the one with infinitely many $1$'s, but in principle you have to pick one and stick with it (or give some rule for determining which cases you will use one and which cases you will use the other). This is the reason you can't just go the easy way and declare that interpreting an element of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N^*}$ as a number in binary is a bijection. You have to use a higher base in one direction to avoid this. And then stitch together the two injections to some nasty amalgamation using Schröder-Bernstein.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact I didn't get your note! could you please clarify it with an example and I will be very thankful

Comment: @Noah16 The number $\frac12$ can be written as $0.1$ in binary. However, it can _also_ be written as $0.01111\ldots$. That's _two_ sequences from $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N^*}$. And you can't have a function from the set of numbers to the set of sequences that gives two sequences as output for some numbers. So you have to choose. (And in order to not get into Axiom of Choice issues, you have to make a single, simulatneous choice for all numbers at the same time.)

Comment: Sorry for all of this but how can I define my choice mathematically. i.e I can't define (mathematically) the function which show my choice among the two sequences

Comment: Yeah, you just say "Whenever there is an option, choose the one with trailing $0$s", assuming that's your choice. Don't confuse "mathematically" with "using formulas" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$ is a complete enumeration of $[0,1]$. I will show it cannot in fact be complete.

- Let $I_0$ be a closed subinterval of $[0,1]$ such that $l(I_0) \le \frac13$ (where $l([a,b]=b-a$ denotes the length of a interval) and such that $f(0) \notin I_0$. This can easily be done.
- Going on by recursion, suppose we have intervals $I_n \subseteq I_{n-1} \subseteq \ldots I_1 \subseteq I_0$ already that satisfy $l(I_n) \le \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$ and $f(k) \notin I_k$ for all $k \le n$, we can partition $I_n$ into three subintervals of a third of its length and at least one of them will not contain $f(n+1)$ and we pick that one as $I_{n+1}$ so we can keep up these conditions.

Now Cantor's nested subinterval theorem (which he proved for just this application, based on completeness of $[0,1]$) or compactness of $[0,1]$  gives us a point $p \in \bigcap_n I_n$ and by construction it cannot be in $f[\mathbb{N}]$ showing that no enumeration can in fact be complete and $[0,1]$ is uncountable.